# How to get user input in discord.py after command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am wondering how to get user input after the command string. I have this command called `p!spam` and I want it to do `p!spam (message) (amount of times)` but I have no clue how to do this. Can someone help me?

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('p!spam'):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_message` method isn't a command, it's an event.

Using the `on_message()` event,

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('p!spam'):
        try:
            spam = split(' ')
            length = len(spam)
            amount = int(spam[length - 1])
            del spam[0]
            del spam[length - 1]
            for i in range (amount):
                await message.channel.send(' '.join(spam))
        except:
            await message.channel.send('Sorry, something went wrong.')

    await client.process_commands(ctx)     # Important for commands to work
```

The message to call this command would look like this (Which is what you were looking for I believe):

> p!spam This is my spam message. 10

**Another method, where the amount is at the beginning:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('p!spam'):
        try:
            spam = split(' ')
            amount = int(spam[1])
            del spam[0]
            del spam[1]
            for i in range (amount):
                await message.channel.send(' '.join(spam))
        except:
            await message.channel.send('Sorry, something went wrong.')

    await client.process_commands(ctx)     # Important for commands to work
```

The message to call this command would look like this:

> p!spam 10 This is my spam message.

---

Doing this with a command will be a lot easier, you can simply do this:

```py
@client.command
async def spam(ctx, amount, *, spam):
    for i in range(int(amount)):
        await ctx.send(spam)
```

The message to call this command would look like this:

> p!spam 10 This is my spam message.

Comment: Why did you hardcode 10 for the number of times the message should be sent? The original question wants the ability to define the number of times to spam the message.

Comment: Thank you so much for actually looking at my question and answering it!! I really appreciate it <3

Comment: @NicholasChen no prob! Please mark this as the solution if it helped you.

Comment: @NicholasChen that's an Upvote, to do that you need at least 15. But to mark this as the solution, you don't need any more than 1 (The check mark below the downvote button)

Comment: oh im dum ;-; sorry

Comment: @NicholasChen don't worry about it, you're new here. Thanks for marking it!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the number of times the message is supposed to be sent before the message for simplicity.
The command syntax for the following code is:

```
p!spam [# of times to repeat] [message]
```

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('p!spam'):
        parts = message.content.split(' ')
        del parts[0]
        number = int(parts.pop(0))
        msg = ' '.join(parts)
        for k in range(number):
            await message.channel.send(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! (btw u forgot the : at the for loop lol)